# What is the best practice in sharing a scope variable among controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of variables (I'll call it *ArrVar*) which is available to all the controllers through a service. This variable has been assigned as a scope variable in *CtrlA* as *$scope.ArrVar*. If a user toggles a button under *CtrlA*, a method attached to *CtrlA* will make changes to *$scope.ArrVar*, update the variable in the service, and present the list using ng-repeat.

But I have a totally separate controller, *CtrlB*, which needs to make changes to the scope variable under *CtrlA*, which is not available to access from *CtrlB*.

I can think of two solutions:

1. a global controller
2. assign the variable at root scope

but both approaches don't seem to be the best practise. Is there any other elegant way of doing it? Two controllers are totally different, so merging won't do it.

Comment: I think most people generally go with SharedServices.  There are a couple questions about them on this site.

Comment: but a service is not allowed to update a scope variable. CtrlB can receive the newly updated ArrVar by using the service, but it doesn't have an access to $scope.ArrVar, which is under the scope of CtrlA

Comment: You can update a variable that belongs to the shared service, and watch that variable from a controller.  When that value changes, CtrlB can perform an action, update another sharedService variable that is being watched by CtrlA, which then triggers another action.

Comment: can't you access your Arr.Var from CtrlB, by initialising the CtrlA instance in CtrlB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you share the data specific to the obj *(like element position data.msg)* it will bind with a service with no watching or anything.

[2 controllers plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xf803TfFIXrVKsnpai1e?p=preview)

```
app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, Shared) {
  $scope.data = Shared;
})
.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, Shared) {
  $scope.data = Shared;
})
.factory('Shared', function() {
  return { msg : ['one','two','three'] }
});

   <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
      <input ng-model="data.msg"/>
      {{data}}
   </div>    
   <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
      <input ng-model="data.msg"/>
     {{data}}
   </div>
```

Comment: Thank you Dylan, but I've tried this approach but the array does not get updated immediately. In fact, there is a delay between each function call, so the previous function call result is passed to the scope... (this might be because the scope variable is updated before the function is done with the new execution) I've tried running $scope.$apply manually but I get an error saying that it is in progress already. I had to use $timeout in order to prevent it from working so. Is there any other way around then timeout?

Comment: If you are waiting for some event to complete then a $watch may be necessary for that controller,  but that should not break the initial binding of the 2. It's hard to say without an example, maybe put up a plunker.

Comment: I finally figured it out. In short, the ArrVar in the service was updated within an API call, so I had to use $apply for instant update. Thanks a lot tho!